# Having trouble keeping a persistent variable in a class

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to write a script that will guess numbers between 1-100, and respond appropriately based on whether users say that the number is too high or too low until it guesses the correct number.  My code runs as is right now (Python 2.7) but the guess doesn't update even though I continue to call a new `make_guess`.  My idea of how it should be going is:

1. Make initial guess of 50
2. Get told whether guess is higher, lower, or correct
3. Adjust guess based on answer returned from function call in 2 and update the `my_guess` variable
4. Continue until told guess is correct

here's my code as it currently stands:

```
class Number_Guesser(object):
    lower_bound = 1
    upper_bound = 100

    def initialize(self,lower_bound,upper_bound):
        self.lower_bound = lower_bound
        self.upper_bound = upper_bound
        self.number_of_guesses = 1

    def guess_and_adjust(self):
        while True:
            self.anticheat()
            my_guess = self.make_guess()
            answer = input('Enter 1 if your number is higher, 2 if it\'s lower, or 3 if I was correct!')
            if answer=='1':
                self.lower_bound = my_guess + 1
                self.number_of_guesses = self.number_of_guesses + 1
            elif answer=='2':
                self.upper_bound = my_guess - 1
                self.number_of_guesses = self.number_of_guesses + 1
            elif answer=='3':
                print 'Woohoooo! I guessed your number in {0} guesses!'.format(self.number_of_guesses)

    def anticheat(self):
        if self.lower_bound > self.upper_bound:
            print 'You cheated! We\'re done here!'
            quit()

    def make_guess(self):
        self.current_guess = (self.upper_bound + self.lower_bound)/2
        print 'my guess is {0}'.format(self.current_guess)
        return self.current_guess

n = Number_Guesser()
n.guess_and_adjust()
```

Essentially, my question is where is my code going wrong such that my `my_guess` variable isn't updating?

Comment: How have you determined that your guess isn't updated? Can you add sample output to your question, and perhaps explain what output you expected instead? I do note that your `while` loop in the `guess_and_adjust()` method never exits, even when the guess is correct.

Comment: You are using the `input()` function in Python 2; this takes user input and interprets that as *a Python expression*. When you enter `1` at the prompt, Python takes that, interprets that a as a Python expression and produces the *integer value `1`*. Your code, however, is testing for *strings*, so unless you entered `'1'` (with literal quotes), your `answer` tests are never going to work and you get an infinite loop instead.

Comment: Instead of using `input()`, you should use `raw_input()` instead, which doesn't try to interpret the input as Python code but just returns the string.

Comment: You also never called the `Number_Guesser.initialize()` method, so `self.number_of_guesses` is never set, so you'd get a `AttributeError: 'Number_Guesser' object has no attribute 'number_of_guesses'` exception when you enter `'1'` or `'2'` or `'3'`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, your wisdom has no limit.  Thank you soo much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points:

- Your code is not working because, in Python 2 (but not 3!), the built-in `input()` function is calls `eval()` (evaluate, a.k.a turn a string into a Python object) on the input string. This means that if you type `1 [ENTER]`, you won't get `"1"`, but `1`, as the result. The best way to change this is to use `raw_input()` instead, which doesn't evaluates the input stream. You should also check for invalid input.
- The `initialize` method is never called. This is because, in Python, the "constructor" function is called `__init__`. Thus, calling `MyClass(1, 2, 3)` will call `MyClass.__init__(self, 1, 2, 3)` if and only if `MyClass.__init__` is defined, and it's not in your case.
- Because of the above, it's not a good idea to declare `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` inside the class. Pass them as arguments to `__init__` instead.
- Instead of using the `x = x + y` pattern, you can say `x += y`.
- You should `quit()` the program (or restart it) when you find the right answer.

Taking that into account, your code should look like this...

```
class Number_Guesser(object):
    def __init__(self,lower_bound,upper_bound):
        self.lower_bound = lower_bound
        self.upper_bound = upper_bound
        self.number_of_guesses = 1

    def guess_and_adjust(self):
        while True:
            self.anticheat()
            my_guess = self.make_guess()
            answer = raw_input('Enter 1 if your number is higher, 2 if it\'s lower, or 3 if I was correct!')
            if answer=='1':
                self.lower_bound = my_guess + 1
                self.number_of_guesses += 1
            elif answer=='2':
                self.upper_bound = my_guess - 1
                self.number_of_guesses += 1
            elif answer=='3':
                print 'Woohoooo! I guessed your number in {0} guesses!'.format(self.number_of_guesses)
                quit()
            else:
                print 'Hey, that input is invalid!'

    def anticheat(self):
        if self.lower_bound > self.upper_bound:
            print 'You cheated! We\'re done here!'
            quit()

    def make_guess(self):
        self.current_guess = (self.upper_bound + self.lower_bound) / 2
        print 'My guess is {0}.'.format(self.current_guess)
        return self.current_guess

n = Number_Guesser(1, 100)
n.guess_and_adjust()
```

Comment: thanks a ton! I don't know why I wrote `initialize` instead of __init__.. must be the time of night :P